# GCC Not Compiling Cython Extension

Tags: python, gcc, cython

I am trying to compile some `.py` files into `.pyd`, using a custom module I wrote called `compileToPyd` (it just handles the various commands associated with the compilation).

I get numerous errors when trying to compile a simple file:

```
path\lib>C:\Python27\python.exe "main_setup.py" build
running build
running build_ext
cythoning main.pyx to main.c

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
?# main.pyd
^
------------------------------------------------------------

main.pyx:1:0: Unrecognized character
building 'main' extension
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
/MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcmain.c /Fobuild\
temp.win32-2.7\Release\main.obj
main.c
main.c(1) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Do not use this file, it is the result
of a failed Cython compilation.
error: command '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.ex
e"' failed with exit status 2

python\lib>"gcc" "main.c" -o "main.pyd" -shared -I"C:\Python27\include" -L"C:\Python27\libs" -lpython
27
main.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cyt
hon compilation.
 #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
```

The file itself is very simple:

```
# main.pyd
# author name
# January 2014

class AuthenticationError(Exception):
    pass

def main():
    '''Main process'''
    import authenticate
    if authenticate.authenticate():
        import some_module
        some_module.main()
    else:
        raise AuthenticationError("Not Authenticated")
```

It is not an executable, and is meant to be imported. The compilation works for other files, so why not this one? Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing here but the fact that the compiler complains about a character *before* the very first visible character in the file suggests to me that the file has been stored with an encoding that includes a byte-order-mark (BOM). Can you verify the encoding of that file? Since you're using Visual Studio, use the advanced file save option on the file menu to check which encoding the file looks like its having. Then try to pick an encoding that doesn't include a BOM.

Comment: I have Notepad++ setup to not use BOM... but apparently it did anyway. You should post that as an answer; it solved my problem :). Thanks by the way!

Comment: OK, posted it as an answer with a bit more information as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
?# main.pyd
```

coupled with your file:

```
# main.pyd
```

indicates that the file has nonprintable characters at the start, not visible to your editor. This is most often caused by your editor inserting a byte-order-mark at the very start of the file, to indicate which encoding was used when saving it.

This BOM will not be visible in the editor, but will of course be there, and for any software that doesn't do the decoding properly, will look odd and out of place.

Enter cython, which did just that.

So to fix this, you need to remove that BOM.

In Visual Studio you can easily do this by opening up the file and using the file menu item "Advanced Save Options":

[image: file menu]

then in the dialog you want to make sure to pick an encoding that doesn't contain the words "with signature":

[image: advanced save options]

the encoding shown here, "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001" is of course the wrong one for your use. I would try the very first item, "Western Europe (Windows) - Codepage 1252".

Please note that encoding changes can in some cases change your file. Things like copyright symbols and accented characters can and will lose their representation if you pick the wrong encoding. As such, for such characters it is probably better to embed them in your source code as escaped characters.